# Why aren't smaller SSD's used solely for OS but instead put on large capacity SSD's?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

I've always been told never to install anything on the same SSD that my OS is on, as it will end up slowing down my SSD and render it impotent in the long run. I recently bought a new computer with 256Gb of SSD (room for expansion thank goodness), and the SSD only has the OS installed.

Given that OS's are about 20-30Gb, why use such a large capacity (comparatively) for just the OS? Is there no downside to filling a SSD?

Edit: 
I've been informed that SSDs aren't affected by available capacity, so the question has been slightly changed to better answer the root issue.

Comment: SSDs are used for OS and Applications mostly. It doesn't really matter what kind of files you put on your SDD, it shouldn't effect windows performance that much as there is no fragmentation.

Comment: "Always been told" by whom? The advice makes little or no sense, unless your OS is on such a tiny SSD <128GB that you would quickly fill it & that would indeed slow it down. My boot SSD is 1TB; I only put small SSDs on machines whole main purpose is storage & remote access rather than 'desktop speed'

Comment: "as it will end up slowing down my SSD and render it impotent in the long run." Whoever told you that doesn't know what they're talking about.

Comment: @Tetsujin Everyone I know who uses them or makes computers. They're reasoning was that if you fill up a 256Gb SSD to over 75%, it would cause slowing in the boot and normal running processes. The question (sort of) is "is there no downside to filling up a SSD other than a full SSD?".

Comment: You ought to re-edit your question, then, to make that the *actual* question. No drive works well when it's too full & SSDs are worse than spinning disks. So, either don't use tiny SSDs [& I consider a 256 to be marginal in that respect] or don't fill them beyond 80%.

Comment: With spinning metal, there could sometimes be an issue using software like Photoshop, especially with other stuff running in the background.  The system could be trying to access OS stuff, plus application code, plus document content, plus swap file content.  It can't access them all at the same time, and going from one to the other involves the relatively slow action of moving the head to another location.  Dividing these onto different physical drives speeds things up, allowing concurrent access.  It's much less of an issue with SSDs because you aren't wasting time moving a head around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've always been told never to install anything on the same SSD that my OS is on, as it will end up slowing down my SSD and render it impotent in the long run.

You've been told wrong.

This myth persists because people don't understand the role that TRIM and garbage collection play on SSDs.  In the (very) early days of SSDs, not all of them supported TRIM, Windows didn't support it until Win7 SP1, and Apple didn't support it on non-Apple branded SSDs until Yosemite.  Further complicating matters, built-in RAID controllers don't support the TRIM command when in RAID mode even if the SSD is the only drive in the system.

The fact is, this is *exactly* the situation TRIM was designed to eliminate.  In practice, all SSDs and all operating systems now support TRIM.  Also, garbage collection algorithms have gotten very good these days and can mitigate slowdowns even in cases where TRIM isn't enabled.  There are plenty of reasons why you'd want an OS on a dedicated drive, but SSD slowdown over time isn't one of them.  That hasn't been true for several years now.

---

**Why do SSDs slow down over time?**

Because cells must be erased first before they can be reprogrammed with new data.  When your SSD is new, all the cells are empty, so they don't have to be erased first and that makes programming them faster.

When you delete a file in Windows (or any other OS for that matter), it does not actually delete anything; it just removes the directory entry for the file.  Eventually, the space that file occupied will get reused for something else down the road, but SSDs don't understand NTFS, HFS+, Ext4, etc. data structures.  As far as they're concerned, the space those files occupied are still allocated blocks.  So when the garbage collector comes around to even out the wear on your SSD, it meticulously preserves that data that is no longer useful for anything.

**How does TRIM fix this?**

TRIM is a special command that the operating system can issue to the SSD to let it know when you've deleted a file.  That way, the garbage collector can actually erase those cells on its own time without worrying about preserving the data they contain.  This keeps your SSD from slowing down over time because there is always stock of fresh, unallocated cells for your SSD to use.

Comment: This is quite helpful, but you mentioned "*There are plenty of reasons why you'd want an OS on a dedicated drive*". Could you provide some of these reasons?

Comment: For one, it's practically impossible to get your data back from a failed SSD, so keeping your data on a regular HD is smart for people who don't do backups regularly.  Dual-booting between OSes is another reason.  If you reload Windows a lot it's helpful to keep it separate.  On servers, a typical setup is to have the OS drives in a RAID-1 and the others in a RAID-5 or -10.  Those are just a few I could think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that your SSD is still limited in I/O, so installing and running more off the same drive will cause more I/O congestion and slow things down. Filling won't necessarily cause more issues, as the answer mentioned, there is no fragmentation, it is more about what is trying to read/write at the same time.

OP also mentioned earlier that filling it can cause issues later, it sounds like you might be referring to the write limits on the silicon. There is a limit to how many times an individual bit can be written (millions of times) which is why SSDs aren't used for RAM.

Comment: @IanM; Your statement is true regardless of whether the drive is an SSD or not. Having two drives will be faster than one in most cases. However, SSDs outperform HDDs in IOps by an order of magnitude, so it's not a concern. If you have two SSDs, then by all means dedicate the smaller one to the OS. But an SSD for the OS and a spinning drive for other stuff will be slower in every case than just one large SSD for everything. Also I wasn't addressing write endurance in my answer, although TRIM helps with that too since it reduces the write amplification that can happen with garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

Until a few months ago SSD's were pretty pricey, so getting a 512 GB SSD wasn't really a thing for many people, so installing programs on normal hard drives was a good alternative since Windows would be running smooth and your programs just take a little longer to load from the normal hard drive. But there's certainly no reason not to install anything on your SSD.

A good idea would be moving all your Libraries (Pictures, Video's, Music,...) and data from your SSD to a big cheap hard drive, and be picky about the software you install on your SSD. Things like your browser or steam can go on your SSD, but put the big game files on your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the expectation was that the OS performance is paramount and that I/O throughput is finite on these SSDs and any competition for that bandwidth is not acceptable.

But in practice, the OS is not where all your time is spent.  This "optimize the OS only" strategy sounds like "elitist" and siloed thinking.  Most of the time you are wanting your programs to execute as quickly as possible. It really makes no difference if the OS slows down a bit because it "Has to Wait for program data to be written/read"; the overall effect of having program + OS rather than just OS on the SSD is that the program operations go faster than if the program was on a normal hard drive.

NOW, I would say that there's one exception.  Because there is so much writing, and re-writing, the swap file should be on a normal hard drive if possible.  Ideally you have enough RAM to not use that swap file, but for some reason, MS Windows (at least up through win 8) prefers to swap OS/Programs/Data out to the swap file in favor of having file cache space.  Maybe there's a way to tune this preference, but this doesn't seem like the optimal way to behave if you aren't re-reading the things in your file cache.